# querying otrs database

Tags: sql, postgresql, otrs

I have a problem with creating a query on a postgresql database from OTRS.  I need to get an asset list with some data that is stored in the CMDB, but I am having trouble with the way that the data is stored.

This query works ok as far as it goes but as soon as I add another left join to get some more data it just runs for ever without returning any results.

As far as I can see, the problem is that all the information is contained in the xml_storage table without any relationships so I need to repeatedly query that table to get the data.  There is also a mix of data types where an integer is stored as a varyable character in some cases and this prevents me from using that value to get additional information from the general catalog.

I have been banging my head against a brick wall for days on this so i would really appreciate any help

```
SELECT 
      asset_value,
      manufacturer_value,
      model_value,
      serial_value,
      fqdn_value,
      array_agg(service),
      purchasedate_value,
      status_value,
      configitem.configitem_number,
      configitem_version.name,
      general_catalog.name

    FROM 
      public.configitem_version,
      public.general_catalog,
      public.configitem 

    left join
      (SELECT
      xml_storage.xml_content_value AS asset_value,
      xml_storage.xml_key
      FROM
      public.xml_storage 
      WHERE
      xml_content_key = '[1]{''Version''}[1]{''Asset Number''}[1]{''Content''}')   as select_asset on last_version_id::int = select_asset.xml_key::int

    left join
      (SELECT
      xml_storage.xml_content_value AS manufacturer_value,
      xml_storage.xml_key
      FROM
      public.xml_storage 
      WHERE
      xml_content_key = '[1]{''Version''}[1]{''Manufacturer''}[1]{''Content''}' ) as select_manufacturer on last_version_id::int = select_manufacturer.xml_key::int

    left join
      (SELECT
      xml_storage.xml_content_value AS model_value,
      xml_storage.xml_key
      FROM
      public.xml_storage 
      WHERE
      xml_content_key = '[1]{''Version''}[1]{''Model''}[1]{''Content''}' ) as select_model on last_version_id::int = select_model.xml_key::int

    left join
      (SELECT
      xml_storage.xml_content_value AS serial_value,
      xml_storage.xml_key
      FROM
      public.xml_storage 
      WHERE
      xml_content_key = '[1]{''Version''}[1]{''SerialNumber''}[1]{''Content''}' ) as select_serial on last_version_id::int = select_serial.xml_key::int

    left join
      (SELECT
      xml_storage.xml_content_value AS fqdn_value,
      xml_storage.xml_key
      FROM
      public.xml_storage 
      WHERE
      xml_content_key = '[1]{''Version''}[1]{''FQDN''}[1]{''Content''}' ) as select_fqdn on last_version_id::int = select_fqdn.xml_key::int

    left join
      (SELECT 
      link_relation.source_key AS "configitem_id", 
      service.name AS "service"
      FROM 
      public.link_relation, 
      public.service
      WHERE 
      link_relation.target_key::int = service.id AND
      link_relation.target_object_id::int = 2 AND link_relation.source_object_id::int = 3
      UNION
      SELECT 
      link_relation.target_key AS "configitem_id", 
      service.name AS "service"
      FROM 
      public.link_relation, 
      public.service
      WHERE 
      link_relation.source_key::int = service.id AND
      link_relation.target_object_id::int = 3 AND link_relation.source_object_id::int = 2) as select_service on configitem.id = configitem_id::int

    left join
      (SELECT
      xml_storage.xml_content_value AS purchasedate_value,
      xml_storage.xml_key
      FROM
      public.xml_storage 
      WHERE
      xml_content_key = '[1]{''Version''}[1]{''PurchaseDate''}[1]{''Content''}' ) as select_purchasedate on last_version_id::int = select_purchasedate.xml_key::int

    left join
      (SELECT
      general_catalog.name AS status_value,
      general_catalog.id
      FROM
      public.general_catalog) as select_status on configitem.cur_depl_state_id::int = select_status.id::int

    WHERE
      configitem.last_version_id = configitem_version.id AND
      configitem.class_id = general_catalog.id AND
      (configitem.class_id = 32 OR configitem.class_id = 33)


    GROUP BY
      asset_value,
      manufacturer_value,
      model_value,
      serial_value,
      fqdn_value,
      purchasedate_value,
      status_value,
      configitem.configitem_number,
      configitem_version.name,
      general_catalog.name

    ;
```

Comment: Looks like an absolutely awful schema. For the query that "runs forever" - what does `explain` report about it? `explain select ...`

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible for you to use the OTRS API rather than a query? It will be a little easier to get your data out that way. 
Also, the ImportExport module allows to export data to .csv files; depending on your needs this might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a quick and dirty web scraping script to get the data I wanted out. A better way, as previously mentioned, would have been to install the import/export library functions but the person with the required skill and permissions to add the extension was tied up. https://github.com/OTRS/ImportExport

https://github.com/colif/Python_Utils/blob/master/OTRS-Web-Scraper-Clean.py